# Добавление элементов в административной части Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

Где не искал, не смог найти следующего описания.
Допустим у меня имеется каталог, состоящий из категорий и элементов категорий. Так вот, скажем элементы имеют характеристики. Можно ли как то реализовать добавление характеристики и её значения при создании или редактировании элемента категории, желательно с использованием AJAX?

Comment: Можно. Как именно зависит от того, как реализованы характеристики. Если это EAV, то инлайнами. Если СУБД - PostgreSQL, то можно использовать HStoreField или JSONField.

Comment: А где про это можно почитать?

Comment: В [документации Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/) описано и использование инлайнов и специфичные для PostgreSQL поля.

Comment: Ну это в общем не то, что ищу.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартно это можно реализовать через `inlines`.

Вот тут примеры с картинками: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site#Inline_editing_of_associated_records